# Is it possible to connect methods, like sort. shift, pop, push and unshift

Tags: javascript, methods

I'm wondering if those that `sort`, `shift`, `pop`, `push`, `unshift` cannot be used whilst connecting to other method.

My current code is the following.

```
function trimmedAverages(arr) {   
    let sum = 0;
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    arr.shift();
    arr.pop();
    arr.map( x => sum += x);
    return Math.round(sum / arr.length);
}
```

And I thought it would be simple if I can connect them like the following one, but it returned an error message..

```
function trimmedAverages(arr) { 
    let sum = 0;
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).shift().pop();
    arr.map( x => sum += x);
    return Math.round(sum / arr.length);
}   
// Error : VM6710:3 Uncaught TypeError: arr.sort(...).shift(...).pop is not a function
// at trimmedAverages (<anonymous>:3:36)
// at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is there anybody can explain for me please?
Thank you so mush in advance.

Comment: None of those returns an array much less the *same* array you operate on. Have you checked their returned types? Why would you expect chaining to work?

Comment: You shouldn't use `map()` if you're not using the return value, use `forEach()` if the body is intended for side effect.

Comment: `shift()` doens't return the modified array, it returns the element that was shifted out.

Comment: @VLAZ actually `sort` does return an array. It returns the same array that called the method just for the purpose of linking methods. But yeah, the other methods can't be linked.

Comment: > VLAZ  
I was misunderstanding their return value.
Your comment makes sense and I understand now. Thank you so much!

Comment: >Barmar 
Your comment about `map()` was informative, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't chain `shift()` and `pop()`, because `shift()` returns the element that was removed, not the updated array.

For your needs you can use `.slice()` to get the sub-array without the first and last elements. And you can chain it from `sort()`, since it returns the array (in addition to modifying it in place).

Since `slice()` doesn't modify the array, you need to subtract 2 from the length when calculating the average.

```js
function trimmedAverages(arr) {
    if (arr.length <= 2) { // return default value if array is too short
      return NaN;
    }
    let sum = 0;
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(1, -1).forEach( x => sum += x);
    return Math.round(sum / (arr.length - 2));
}

console.log(trimmedAverages([1, 3, 10, 5, -6, 19, 20, -8]));
```

Comment: There is now the new `toSpliced()` method we can use for chaining:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced

Comment: @ChunkyChunk They don't need to splice into the array, they're just extracting a slice.